# Image not saving properly in blob field (Angular App to Python)

Tags: python, mysql, angularjs, image, blob

I'm trying to save image from `angular App` to `mysql` blob field in `python` but Image not saving properly.

This is how I'm converting image to byte-array

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer($scope.UserImage);
reader.onload = function(e){
     var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
     $scope.ImageArr = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
};
```

I'm getting this `$scope.ImageArr` as `dict` in python having key-value list, then I get values from it like this

```
userByte =bytearray(ImageArr.values())
```

But when I save this `userByte` in mysql's Blob field, it saves some bytes there but that is not a proper image.

Any guesses what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing??  Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**Edited: (Updated code that worked for me)**

First I convert my image to base64 through this code

```
reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e) { //callback after files finish loading
    var img = e.target.result;
    $scope.ImageArr = img;
}
reader.readAsDataURL($scope.UserImage); //once defined all callbacks, begin reading the file
```

then In python i encoded it in bytes like this

```
bytes(UserImage,"utf-8")
```

This works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for as a `hint`
**you can save base64 image easily rather than byte arrays**

Comment: your hint did my work... I added latest code in my question edited part. 
Thank you